# JAX-RS deserialization of empty string instead of objects

Tags: jersey, jax-rs

JAX-RS (Jersey) is failing at deserializing the following:

```
{
"coverageStores": ""
}
```

Now coverageStores is supposed to be an object, so I would expect the json to be:

```
{
"coverageStores": null
}
```

instead, but it is not.

Is there a way to tell JAX-RS to handle that empty string as if it was a null object? I saw about ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRING_AS_NULL_OBJECT but I would like to use it with annotation ideally.

Comment: Thanks, I got it working in the end using the method I just posted

Answer (score 0):

FWISW, I ended up doing it like this:

```
private static JacksonJsonProvider jacksonJsonProvider = new JacksonJaxbJsonProvider().configure(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRING_AS_NULL_OBJECT, true);

// in method
WebTarget webTarget = ClientBuilder.newClient()
                .register(jacksonJsonProvider)
                .target(urlPath);
etc...
```

I couldn't find an annotation for it, but it's fine like this.